# Cross table with zero counts

Tags: r, crosstab

Maybe this is simple, but I could not find a solution.
The problem is zero counts in a cross table in **R**. If all the elements in a row or column of the cross table, the `table` command does not show that row or column. As far as I can see, there is a solution with `tabulate` command for single vector case, but I can not find solution for cross tabs.

A simple example of "what I get" and "what I want" is below.

```
a <- c(rep("a", 4), rep("b", 4))
b <- rep("a", 8)

table(letter1 = a, letter2 = b)

# What I get

#        letter2
# letter1 a
#       a 4
#       b 4

# What I want

#        letter2
# letter1 a b
#       a 4 0
#       b 4 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert `b` to a factor and specify appropriate levels.

```
table(letter1 = a, letter2 = factor(b, levels = unique(a)))
#       letter2
#letter1 a b
#      a 4 0
#      b 4 0
```